# Last page (uploade page) keeps going back, How to stay on same page in selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a selenium webdriver application that navigates through java applet folders and reaches to a specific one, and then uploads a specific zip file

let's call these folders: **folder1** > **folder2** > **folder3**

When I reach **folder 3**, there is a dropdown that looks like the picture below usually on top of all folders. That allows me to upload a file to that specific folder I am at.

[image]

When I click on the **Upload File** button, it takes me to another page where I could select a file and upload it

picture below shows part of how it looks

[image]

**PROBLEM:**

When I upload the file, it is uploading to **folder 2**. I tried to understand why but could not figure it out. So I tried to comment the upload steps and just reach my final destination as the page where I upload a file. However the page reaches there and then refreshes and goes back immediately in a fraction of a second to folder 3 page.

during the process of upload, the page is jumping backwards and allowing the file to go to **folder** 2 instead of **folder 3**. Not sure if that is the issue but it seems most likely

Here is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("URL")


#click on folder 1
folder1_wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
folder1_element = folder1_wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT,'folder1')))
folder1_link = driver.find_element_by_link_text('folder1')
folder1_link.click()

#click on folder 2
folder2_wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
folder2_element = folder2.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT,'folder2')))
folder2_link = driver.find_element_by_link_text('folder2')
folder2_link.click()

#click on folder 3
folder3_wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
folder3_element = folder3.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT,'folder3')))
folder3_link = driver.find_element_by_link_text('folder3')
folder3_link.click()


#CLICK ON FOLDER OPTION DROPDOWN MENU
folder_wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
folder_element = folder_wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID,'ext-gen55')))
folder_link = driver.find_element_by_id('ext-gen55')
folder_link.click()

#CLICK ON UPLOAD BUTTON IN DROPDOWN MENU
upload_wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
upload_element = upload_wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, 'ext-gen285')))
upload_link = driver.find_element_by_id('ext-gen267')
upload_link.click()


#at this point the page stay in upload path for couple of seconds and then goes back immediatly to folder3

#select folder link
select_link = driver.find_element_by_class_name('members_file')
select_link.send_keys("C:\\Users\\myUser\\Desktop\\test.zip")

#submit uploading folder
ok_link = driver.find_element_by_class_name("borderButton")
ok_link.click()
```

Any possible solution for that problem ? is there a way to stay on the upload page ?

Comment: Are you have to switch to another page so the webdriver gets the control over the page. refer :- http://seleniumwebdriverfaq.blogspot.in/2012/02/how-can-i-switch-webdriver-control-to_4426.html

Comment: Is it possible to expand on that with an answer below ? Such as opening a new tab when clicking on upload button. @ShubhamJain

Comment: Do you want to do operation on upload button page??

Comment: Never mind I added it with `upload_link.send_keys(Keys.COMMAND + 't')` but it did not work turns out I cannot open a new tab in a java applet or it will take u back to folder 1 @ShubhamJain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you said :- 
"When I click on the Upload File button, it takes me to another page where I could select a file"

Now I assumed that now you want to do operation on page where your upload functionality is present. For that you need to instruct selenium to pass control to next page otherwise selenium try to find that element on the same page.

To switch your control in python you can refer below link as I am java guy and this platform is not allowing me to share any other language code which is not used by OP(you):-

Refer from 3.4

```
http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/navigating.html
```

Hope it will help you :)